# Calculating risk factors for waste management system using SQL database

Tags: qgis, sql, spatialite, sql-view

I am working on a waste management system where I need to prioritize actions based on risk factors associated with different types of waste, including industrial and sewage waste. The system utilizes a SQL database to store information about contaminated objects, such as their age, position, and type of contamination.

Here is an overview of the database schema:

```
-- Contaminated objects table
CREATE TABLE ContaminatedObject (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    age INTEGER,
    position POINT,
    extension REAL
);

-- Sewage contamination table
CREATE TABLE SewageContamination (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    contaminatedObjectId INTEGER,
    sewageType TEXT,
    sewageVolume FLOAT,
    owner TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (contaminatedObjectId) REFERENCES ContaminatedObject(id)
);

-- Industrial contamination table
CREATE TABLE IndustrialContamination (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    contaminatedObjectId INTEGER,
    industrialWasteType TEXT,
    industrialWasteVolume TEXT,
    owner TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (contaminatedObjectId) REFERENCES ContaminatedObject(id)
);

-- Issues table
CREATE TABLE Issue (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    objectId INTEGER,
    issueType TEXT,
    date TIMESTAMP,
    documentation TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (objectId) REFERENCES ContaminatedObject(id)
);

-- Historical records table for documentation
CREATE TABLE HistoricalRecord (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    objectId INTEGER,
    action TEXT,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (objectId) REFERENCES ContaminatedObject(id)
);

-- City bodies table
CREATE TABLE City (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    cityName TEXT,
    position POINT
);

-- Water bodies table
CREATE TABLE WaterBody (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    waterBodyname TEXT,
    position POINT
);
```

Here are the values that i have inserted into the tables:

```
-- Insert sample data into the ContaminatedObject table
INSERT INTO ContaminatedObject (name, age, position, extension) VALUES
    ('Object 1', 20, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10 20)'), 50.5),
    ('Object 2', 30, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(30 40)'), 60.7),
    ('Object 3', 25, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(50 60)'), 70.2);

-- Insert sample data into the SewageContamination table
INSERT INTO SewageContamination (contaminatedObjectId, sewageType, sewageVolume, owner) VALUES
    (1, 'chromium', 100.5, 'Owner A'),
    (2, 'arsenic', 200.7, 'Owner B');

-- Insert sample data into the IndustrialContamination table
INSERT INTO IndustrialContamination (contaminatedObjectId, industrialWasteType, industrialWasteVolume, owner) VALUES
    (1, 'arsenic', 145, 'Owner C'),
    (3, 'arsenic', 105, 'Owner D');

-- Insert sample data into the City table
INSERT INTO City (cityName, position) VALUES
    ('City 1', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(15 25)'));

-- Insert sample data into the WaterBody table
INSERT INTO WaterBody (waterBodyname, position) VALUES
    ('Lake 1', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(20 30)')),
    ('Lake 2', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(40 50)'));
```

The criteria for prioritizing actions include:

1. Age Criterion: Facilities older than 40 years are prioritized for inspection.
2. Proximity to Water Bodies: Facilities within 250 meters of a water body are prioritized due to the higher risk of contamination affecting the water body.
3. Classification Schema: The prioritization considers factors such as the type and volume of contamination, proximity to urban areas, and other relevant considerations.

To calculate the risk factors, I have attempted to create a view named "RiskReport" using SQL. Here is the SQL code snippet:

```
CREATE VIEW RiskReport AS 
SELECT 
    co.id AS objectId, 
    co.name, 
    co.age, 
    ST_AsText(co.position) AS position_text, 
    co.extension, 
    CASE 
        WHEN sewageRiskScore = 30 AND sewageRiskScore = 30 AND industrialRiskScore 40 THEN 20 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS ageFactor 
FROM 
    ContaminatedObject co 
INNER JOIN 
    SewageContamination sc ON co.id = sc.contaminatedObjectId 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        sc.contaminatedObjectId, 
        CASE 
            WHEN sewageType = 'arsenic' THEN 30 
            WHEN sewageType = 'chromium' THEN 25 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS sewageContaminationFactor 
    FROM 
        SewageContamination sc 
    ) AS contamination ON sc.contaminatedObjectId = contamination.contaminatedObjectId 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        sc.contaminatedObjectId, 
        CASE 
            WHEN sewageVolume > 100 THEN 15 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS volumeFactor 
    FROM 
        SewageContamination sc 
    ) AS volume ON sc.contaminatedObjectId = volume.contaminatedObjectId 
) AS sewageRiskFactors ON co.id = sewageRiskFactors.contaminatedObjectId 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        ic.contaminatedObjectId, 
        (ageFactor + industrialContaminationFactor + volumeFactor) AS industrialRiskScore 
    FROM 
        IndustrialContamination ic 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            ic.contaminatedObjectId, 
            CASE 
                WHEN age > 40 THEN 20 
                ELSE 0 
            END AS ageFactor 
        FROM 
            ContaminatedObject co 
        INNER JOIN 
            IndustrialContamination ic ON co.id = ic.contaminatedObjectId 
        ) AS age ON ic.contaminatedObjectId = age.contaminatedObjectId 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            ic.contaminatedObjectId, 
            CASE 
                WHEN industrialWasteType = 'arsenic' THEN 30 
                WHEN industrialWasteType = 'chromium' THEN 25 
                ELSE 0 
            END AS industrialContaminationFactor 
        FROM 
            IndustrialContamination ic 
        ) AS contamination ON ic.contaminatedObjectId = contamination.contaminatedObjectId 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            ic.contaminatedObjectId, 
            CASE 
                WHEN industrialWasteVolume > 100 THEN 15 
                ELSE 0 
            END AS volumeFactor 
        FROM 
            IndustrialContamination ic 
        ) AS volume ON ic.contaminatedObjectId = volume.contaminatedObjectId 
    ) AS industrialRiskFactors ON co.id = industrialRiskFactors.contaminatedObjectId;
```

However, I am encountering difficulties with this approach, and the view is not producing the desired results. Specifically, I am struggling to properly incorporate the criteria mentioned above into the calculation of risk scores for sewage and industrial waste, especially criteria 2.

When i run `select * from RiskReport` this is what I get:

| objectId | name | age | position_text | extension | sewageRiskLevel | industrialRiskLevel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Object 1 | 20 | POINT(10 20) | 50.5 | Low Risk | High Risk |
| 2 | Object 2 | 30 | POINT(30 40) | 60.7 | Low Risk | High Risk |
| 3 | Object 3 | 25 | POINT(50 60) | 70.2 | High Risk | Low Risk |
| 4 | Object 4 | 11 | POINT(40 71) | 48.2 | High Risk | Low Risk |

I'm unsure how to accurately read on the risk, at the moment my code doesn't do such a good calculation and I'm unsure if it even calculates the positions correctly, given the criteria. What I want is as the view table is showing, what I have problems with is calculating the risk properly. Especially the position points from cities and water bodies.

What I want is something like this:

| objectId | name | age | position_text | extension | nearWaterRisk | nearCityRisk | distanceToWater | distanceToCity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Object 1 | 20 | POINT(10 20) | 50.5 | Low Risk | High Risk | - | - |
| 2 | Object 2 | 30 | POINT(30 40) | 60.7 | Low Risk | High Risk | - | - |
| 3 | Object 3 | 25 | POINT(50 60) | 70.2 | High Risk | Low Risk | - | - |
| 4 | Object 4 | 11 | POINT(40 71) | 48.2 | High Risk | Low Risk | - | - |

Where distanceToWater and distanceToCity, tells me how close said waste is to the city and which has a highest risk to being a problem. Where water takes priority over the cities.

How can I refine the SQL code to accurately calculate the risk factors based on the specified criteria?

Additionally, I am open to suggestions for alternative approaches to achieve this task effectively within the SQL database framework.